# Global symbolic functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have the following code:

```
global a;
syms x y;
a(x,y) = 1+0*x*t; %this will be changed in future
```

In 2012b this code gives an error:

```
Error using sym/subsindex (line 1367)
Indexing input must be numeric, logical or ':'.
```

When I place line `global a` after `a(x,y)=1+0*x*t`, this code starts work, but gives a warning that "future versions of MATLAB will require defining variables as global before using". That's strange behaviour.

Why can't MATLAB just create global symbolic function? Why does MATLAB try to interpret this as array instead of symbolic function?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a = 1+0*x*t;`?

Comment: @LuisMendo: that's a symbolic expression but not a symfun. @EverOid: Try `a=symfun(1+0*x*t, [x t])`

Comment: This occurs in 2013b as well. Clearly seems like a bug. The provided workaround avoids the warning at least. @Everv0id, you should [file a bug report](https://mathworksservicerequest.secure.force.com/cp_case_new) with the MathWorks. Also consider if you actually need to be using globals. They are rarely necessary or the best solution.